# Getting Amazon ASIN from URL with Powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing

I recently got a job where I add products to Amazon and my lazy self finds it to time consuming to grab the ASIN (Amazon Standard Identification Number) from a product and paste it in to our manager. I did some research and I think the best way to automate this would be using Windows Powershell. The only problem is that I've never used Powershell.

Basically I need a program to open a text box where we can enter the Amazon product link and it will pull the ASIN number and input it to our web manager.

Is it possible? Can I make it in PowerShell? Is there a better way than PowerShell?

I've got the text box to open and got the input to be stored in a variable, but that's about it.

I can get my way through most programming languages, but PowerShell has a lot of functions and I didn't want to spend the time learning it all.

Comment: Can you show an example of a product and what asin you expect to get? Also how does your manager work? Does it expose a web interface?

Comment: What format is the link? Most product links on Amazon contain the ASIN, no need to actually visit the site

Comment: "PowerShell has a lot of functions and I didn't want to spend the time learning it all"

Not what SO is for at all!

Comment: @Martin Brandl We add pet products like [link](https://www.amazon.com/East-Side-Collection-Carolina-Raspberry/dp/B0055LVII2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1470481804&sr=8-1&keywords=0721343333425) and from this product I would like to grab B0055LVII2.

Comment: This is easy. Do you have a list of links in a text file or where do you get the links? Also, what do you want to do with the ASIN then? Would it be suiteable for you if I just put the ASIN in the Clipboard?

Comment: @Martin Brandl Putting it in the clipboard would be great, and we scan the item on amazon and grab the link from there so we don't have a list of them but it only takes a second to get it. And I was already able to make the script open the product on amazon now I just need it to get the ASIN and put it in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URL already contains the ASIN, all you have to do is to use a simple regex to grab it:

```
$link = 'https://www.amazon.com/East-Side-Collection-Carolina-Raspberry/dp/B0055LVII2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1470481804&sr=8-1&keywords=0721343333425'
[regex]::Match($link, '\/dp\/([^\/]+)').Groups[1].Value | clip
```

The last pipe (`| clip`) will put the ASIN to your clipboard so all you have to do is to change the `$link`...